# paypal the merchant does not accept payment of this type

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are having major trouble when we pay using direct credit card payment from mobile application development. To the live transaction we cannot able to use direct credit card payment.

While using Credit Card: "The merchant does not accept payments of this type."

We are developing the mobile application using ionic framework. Using the ionic-paypal plugin we implemented and Sandbox flow has been verified success using Paypal  REST API. For the live account not working.  Paypal develper page i cannot able to enable the "credit card payment" from the following url "https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus"

Any additional permission require to live transaction or any other steps and solutions to complete this

Answer (score 0):

PayPal REST API Credit Card payment instrument currently available for US and UK PRO account. If you tried with some other countries except from these two, you'll get an error.

You can read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#direct-credit-card-payments)